# Fast picturebox display in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, picturebox

is any way to load and display faster 100 (10x10) pictureboxes? All images are sized 40x40 pixels (5KB). I think there is better way than in my code but i'm too big newbie right now.

```
PictureBox[,] tile = new PictureBox[10,10];

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tile[j, i] = new PictureBox();
        if (mapa[j,i] == 0) tile[j, i].ImageLocation = folder + @"\\Images\ground.bmp";
        if (mapa[j, i] == 1) tile[j, i].ImageLocation = folder + @"\\Images\\lava.bmp";
        if (mapa[j, i] == 2) tile[j, i].ImageLocation = folder + @"\\Images\\win.bmp";

        tile[j, i].Location = new Point(10 + (41 * j), 10 + (41 * i));
        tile[j, i].SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        progressBar1.Increment(1); 
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use one.  Create a Bitmap and draw your images into it.  You'll need Graphics.FromImage() to create a Graphics object and use its DrawImage() method to draw the images into the bitmap.  Any half decent book about Winforms will cover this.

Comment: @Hans Passant Today I had more time on the programming and I must say DrawImage() method work very fast. Thank you. I dont know why i think "100 picture box" method is awesome idee. ;]